# Cannot convert method group 'Save Session' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates, login-control

I keep getting this error each time upon Logon:

```
 Cannot convert method group 'Save Session' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?
```

**Here's my Login1 Component Code behind:**

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    Boolean blnresult;
    blnresult = false;

    // Pass UserName  and Password from login1 control to an authentication function which will check will check the user name and password from sql server.
    // Then will retrun a true or false value into blnresult variable
    blnresult = Authentication(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);

    // If blnresult has a true value then authenticate user 
    if (blnresult == true)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, true);
        SaveSession();
        // This is the actual statement which will authenticate the user
        e.Authenticated = true;
    }
    else
    {            // If user faild to provide valid user name and password
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "Materialize.toast('הפרטים שהוקשו שגויים.', 4000);", true);
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }

}
```

**SaveSession() Code:**

```
protected void SaveSession()
{
    var connn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Db"].ConnectionString);

    // Save SessionID in db
    string querySession = "UPDATE Users SET SessionID = @SessionID WHERE Id = @Id";

    MySqlCommand cmdSession = new MySqlCommand(querySession.Replace("'", ""), connn);
    cmdSession.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SessionID", Session.SessionID);
    cmdSession.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", GetUserId(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password));
    GlobalFunctions.CheckCon();

    try
    {
        connn.Open();
        cmdSession.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        connn.Close();
    }
    GlobalFunctions.getUserid(GetUserId(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password));

    GlobalFunctions.logged = true;

}
```

What am I missing..?
I tried to find a solution out there but no solution points at me solution exactly, I don't use delegate anywhere - where is this error coming from?
Thanks :)

Comment: When do you get the error message?

Comment: upon debugging. Code of SaveSession never gets executed.

Comment: It sounds like you forgot the parentheses on the method but I see them in the code above.  Is there anywhere where you see `SaveSession` without parentheses?

Comment: I'm on it for an hour now... can't find what goes wrong.

Comment: Is there any specific line of code where the debugger shows this error?

Comment: is the space between Save and Session a typo? could you give a complete exception call stack?

Comment: Yes it is. originally there's no space, I checked it.

Comment: two hints: 1) do a solutionwide find in all files, case sensitive and match whole word, for `SaveSession` 2) rename the method and its call  in your code, then debug and see if the exception follows your rename or not

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using a delegate anywhere, you are probably seeing this error message because you have omitted the parentheses after the method call for `SaveSession()`.  Take a look at your code to ensure there is nowhere where you put simply `SaveSession` without the parentheses.